# Using mean value theorem in $\mathbb R_n$ with directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb R_n\to\mathbb R$. Suppose that for each unit vector $u$ in $\mathbb R_n$, the directional derivative of $u$, $D(f(a+tu))$ exists for $t$ between $0$ and $1$. We want to show that $f(a+u) - f(a) = D(f(a+tu))$ for some $t$ between $0$ and $1$. Note: the directional derivative of $u$ in $\mathbb R_n$ is given by $D(f(a))= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(a+tu) - f(a)}{t}$.

I tried applying the mean value theorem to $f(a)$ and $f(a+tu)$, which yields a $D(f(c))\cdot u$. I then tried to get that quantity to look like the directional derivative, which did not work. Any tips on how to get started would be helpful here.

Comment: You have strange notations. Your $f$ is not differentiable, so $Df$ does not necessarily exist. But note that $f(a+u) - f(a) = f(a+1\cdot u) - f(a + 0 \cdot u)$ and use the mean value theorem.