# Specific case of Mean Value Theorem for partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function in the closed segment $[x,y] \subset \Omega $, such that the partial derivative with respect to the j-th variable $( \frac{\partial f(x)}{ \partial x_{j}})$ is defined in the segment $ (x,y) $. Prove that $ \exists z \in (x,y) $ such that:
$$f(y) - f(x) = \frac{\partial f(z)}{ \partial x_{j}} (y_{j} - x_{j})$$

Honestly I'm really surprised that I ended up having to ask this, because at first I thought the prove would just  closely follow the same structure from similar theorems. But my main problem is that the conditions I'm given restrict me from using the theorems that I am comfortable with. Most similar questions I've found (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311259/using-mean-value-theorem-in-mathbb-r-n-with-directional-derivatives) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592457/prove-multi-dimensional-mean-value-theorem)) refer to different MVTs (which I actually already know), but can't seemingly be applied here. The [proof for the first one](http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/0/5/31054371/msii-lectures-2012-05-04-signed.pdf) (it's Theorem 36, just using this as a reference) doesn't work here because it only proves the existence of a directional derivative, where the direction is the one from the segment, so for example in my case it could only prove the directional derivative in the direction $ \frac{y-x}{||y-x||} $. In fact, the proof does require that the limit $ \lim_{t \rightarrow t_{0}} g(t)$ is only evaluated for points that are in the segment, because otherwise you can't guarantee that the composition of f and g are continuous, and can't apply the single-variable MVT.

The second one does imply existence of all partial derivatives, but it requires differentiability so that's out of the question.

What I gathered from both proofs is that they are usually revolved around reducing the multivariable functions down to functions in $ \mathbb{R} $, where we can use the MVT for the single-variable case. However, I don't know how to do that in this case. I think that my main problem comes from the fact that I don't know what is the direction of the segment $[x,y]$.

Could anyone please give me a hint on how to build a function that lets me reduce this problem to a single-variable case? Or should I take a completely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may have $x_j=y_j$ but $f(x) \neq f(y)$. So the assertion is false.

Comment: Thanks for making it explicit, now it makes sense. But since that's the case, then what's a minimal condition that could be added to make it true? Continuity in the whole domain? Or a restriction to the segment?

Comment: @JoaquinC. You can expect such a result to be true only when  the line segment is parallel to $x_j-$ axis and in this case it reduces to MVT in $\mathbb  R$.